# Mint updater fails after installing Canon printer drivers

Tags: dependencies, apt-get, linux-mint

I'm using linux Mint 17.2 "Rafaela". Today I installed drivers for Canon iP2700 series. The drivers' deb package relied on "libtiff4" package, but system uses "libtiff5", so I forced the installation with

```
sudo dpkg --force-depends -i cnijfilter-*
```

It worked: the printer works perfectly but mint updater fails to update, it says "cnijfilter-ip2700series package will be removed". Of course I don't want to remove it. What shall I do?

**One more thing**: if I do

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

I get something like (I'm translating from spanish) "cnijfilter-ip2700series has unresolved dependencies: Depends: libtiff4 but is not possible to install. Try to use -f option"

and if I do

```
sudo apt-get -f dist-upgrade
```

it says "cnijfilter-ip2700series will be removed"

Anyway, I prefer to use mint updater since apt-get seems to disrupt system settings, so I would prefer a solution that relies on mint updater.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The system thinks that your installation of cnijfilter it is broken, because it has a missing dependency. Since it is unsatisfiable, suggesting to uninstall the package is actually a quite good solution.

You have multiple options:

- It appears that you can [download the source of the driver and compile it yourself](http://www.canon-europe.com/support/consumer_products/products/fax__multifunctionals/inkjet/pixma_mx_series/pixma_mx885.aspx?type=drivers&driverdetailid=tcm:13-823916&os=LINUX&language=EN).
- A simpler solution is download & manally install a package for libtiff4,  [either from Ubuntu](http://packages.ubuntu.com/de/precise/libtiff4) or [Debian](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/libtiff4). Both versions of the package should be installable on your system (without unsatisfiable dependencies). This is what I did on my (also mint, also with these Cancon drivers) system.
- You can patch the dependency out of the package to make apt *think* that everything is fine. The applications within the package that rely on libtiff4 will be broken, of course, but the actual driver (`/usr/lib/cups/backend/cnijusb`) is not one of them. Patching it is quite easy:

  ```
  # Unpack the deb package:
  $ ar x cnijfilter-..._amd64.deb
  # This will create 3 files: data.tar.gz, control.tar.gz and debian-binary

  # Unpack control.tar.gz:
  $ mkdir DEBIAN
  $ cd DEBIAN
  $ tar xzf ../control.tar.gz

  # Edit the newly created control file:
  $ your_favorite_editor control
  # now, in the editor, remove the libtiff4 dependency from the Depends line

  # Repack everything into a new deb file:
  $ rm ../control.tar.gz
  $ tar czf ../control.tar.gz *
  $ cd ..
  $ ar r cnijfilter-..._amd64.deb contol.tar.gz
  ```

  Afterwards, your updated deb file does no longer have libtiff4 as a dependency. Let apt uninstall the installed version such that it no longer complains, and then install your newly created package.